# Is there a find and replace method in Google Spreadsheet api?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a find and replace method in Google Spreadsheet api? there somewhere I found find and replace request but unable to determine what URL should I use for that. Google's documentation isn't much clear about that.

Comment: About `find and replace request`, in this case, I guessed that you wanted to use [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest). If my understanding is correct, this can be used with ["Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). You can see the endtpoint and the request body at those official documents.

Comment: @Tanaike Consider adding a answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About `find and replace request`, I guessed that you might be thinking of [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest), you can use this with ["Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) of Sheets API.

The sample request is as follows.

#### Endpoint and request body

The content type of the request header is `application/json`.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate
```

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "findReplace": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "find": "sample",
        "replacement": "replaced",
        "matchEntireCell": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- In this request body, a value of `sample` is searched and it is replaced with a value of `replaced` in the specification sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- If you want to search and replace in all sheets, please modify `"sheetId": 0` to `"allSheets": true`.
- Regex can be also used.

#### Sample curl command:

The sample curl command is as follows. I thought that the sample curl command might help to think of the script you are using.

```bash
$ curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]:batchUpdate' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"findReplace":{"allSheets":false,"sheetId":0,"find":"","replacement":"","matchEntireCell":false}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

#### Sample javascript:

When I saw your tag, I noticed `javascript`. So, I added Javascript as a sample script. In this sample, the sheet ID of `0` is used. Please modify this for your actual situation.

```js
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId,
    resource: {
      requests: [
        {
          findReplace: {
            sheetId: 0,
            find: "sample",
            replacement: "replaced",
            matchEntireCell: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }).then(({result}) => {
    console.log(result)
}, function(reason) {
  console.error(reason.result.error.message);
});
```

- If you want to see the whole script of Javascript, you can check [Quickstart for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). In this case, I think that you can use this script at `// Fetch first 10 files`. But, before you use this, please modify the scope from `const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';` to `const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';`.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `javscript` tag in your tag. If you want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script. I think that [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) instead of Sheets API might be suitable.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)